# Magento 2 - Can't Change Page Layout Columns With An Override Layout File

Tags: magento2, overrides

I am able to change the layout columns if I extend a page's layout file, but it won't work if I use an override layout file. What do you have to do to change a page's layout columns with an override?

The code that works with a layout extension, eg., in `\app\design\frontend\MyVendor\Theme\Magento_Catalog\layout\catalog_product_view.xml` is:

```
<page layout="2columns-left" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
</page>
```

But then if I add the `layout="2columns-left` part to an override file at `\app\design\frontend\MyVendor\Theme\Magento_Catalog\layout\override\base\catalog_product_view.xml` then the layout columns don't change. Is that not possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To override a page layout you should use `page_layout` directory instead of `layout`.

`\app\design\frontend\MyVendor\Theme\Magento_Catalog\page_layout\override\base\catalog_product_view.xml`

Comment: I notice that the subfolder under `override` needs to be `base`. But what does `base` refer to?

Comment: Nice ;) working

Comment: This does not work. Results in error: 
"Exception #0 (LogicException): Overriding view file '/srv/public_html/app/design/frontend/{vendor}/{theme}/Magento_Catalog/page_layout/override/base/catalog_category_view.xml' does not match to any of the files."

Comment: I upgraded to 2.4.3 and layout stopped working. With this I fixed issue.

Answer (score -1):

move el override file to /Magento_Catalog/page_layout/catalog_product_view.xml this work!

reference http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/layout-override.html